# Find nearest point in other dataframe (WITH A LOT OF DATA)

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, nearest-neighbor, geopandas

The problem is simple i have two DataFrame :

- one with 90 000 apartment and their latitude/longitude
- and one with 3 000 pharmacy and their latitude/longitude

And i want to create a new variable for all my apartments : 'distance of the nearest pharmacy'

For this i tried two methods **which spend to much time**:

**First method :** I created a matrix with my apartments in row and my pharmacies in columns and the distance betwenn them in the intersection, after that i just take the min of the matrix to have a column vector of 90 000 value

I just use a double for with numpy :

```
m,n=len(result['latitude']),len(pharma['lat'])
M = np.ones((m,n))
for i in range(m):
     for j in range(n):
        if (result['Code departement'][i]==pharma['departement'][j]):
            M[i,j] =(pharma['lat'][j]-result['latitude'][i])**2+(pharma['lng'][j]-result['longitude'] [i])**2
```

ps : i know that the wrong formula for lat/long but the appartments are in the same region so it's a good aproximation

**Second method :** I use the solution from this topics (who are the same problem but with less data)
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/geopandas-find-nearest-point-in-other-dataframe

I used geopandas et the nearest method :

```
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
pts3 = pharma.geometry.unary_union


def near(point, pts=pts3):
     nearest = pharma.geometry == nearest_points(point, pts)[1]
     return pharma[nearest].geometry.get_values()[0]

appart['Nearest'] = appart.apply(lambda row: near(row.geometry), axis=1)
```

And as i said, **both methods spend too much time**, after 1 hour of running my pc/notebook crashed and it failed.

**My final question :** have you a optimized method to go faster ? it is possible ? If it's already optimized, i will buy a other PC but which criteria but what criteria to look for to have a PC capable of doing such a quick calculation ?

Comment: I think you should be following the second answer to the question you refer us to, ie the one using a spatial index to avoid an all:all calculation of distances.

Comment: Have you a example ? Because i have the impression that i already use a spatial index in the second solution with geopandas and this changed nothing for the time spent.

Comment: Then I have misunderstood your code and my earlier comment was mistaken.

Comment: Just to clarify, the second option based on shapely does not use spatial index.

Comment: No no it's certainly me that don't understood what are a spatial index. Have you one example ? one link ?

Comment: You can start here https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/ but keep in mind that this is for intersection. I have implemented similar stuff here https://docs.momepy.org/en/stable/_modules/momepy/elements.html#get_network_id . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess a [**Ball Tree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree) is an appropriate structure for this task.

You can use the [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) implementation, see the code below for an example adapted to your case :

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

## Create the two GeoDataFrame to replicate your dataset
appart = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
        'geometry': Point(a, b),
        'x': a,
        'y': b,
    } for a, b in zip(np.random.rand(100000), np.random.rand(100000))
])

pharma = gpd.GeoDataFrame([{
        'geometry': Point(a, b),
        'x': a,
        'y': b,
    } for a, b in zip(np.random.rand(3000), np.random.rand(3000))
])

# Create a BallTree 
tree = BallTree(pharma[['x', 'y']].values, leaf_size=2)

# Query the BallTree on each feature from 'appart' to find the distance
# to the nearest 'pharma' and its id
appart['distance_nearest'], appart['id_nearest'] = tree.query(
    appart[['x', 'y']].values, # The input array for the query
    k=1, # The number of nearest neighbors
)
```

With this method you can solve your problem pretty quickly (the above example, on my computer, took less than a second to find the index of the nearest point, out of 3000 points, on an input dataset of 100000 points).

By default the `query` method of `BallTree` is returning the distance to the nearest neighbor and its id.
If you want you can disable returning the distance of this nearest neighbor by setting the `return_distance` parameter to `False`.
If you really only care about the distance, you can save only this value :

```
appart['distance_nearest'], _ = tree.query(appart[['x', 'y']].values, k=1)
```

Comment: Ooooh thanks man, its so efficiency and fast :o 
It's a very good news :)

I was trying to make a segmentation by region to have less calculs and it worked too but less than BallTree

**Last question :** how have a distance in kilometer with balltree on a latitude and longitude ?

Because here i have a distance but i don't know chat it represent really (ans if it has sense).

Comment: I think you should convert your `pharma` and your `appart` geodataframes to use a projected coordinate system (such as 'epsg:2154' for France or 'epsg:3035' for Europe) by doing `appart.to_crs(epsg=2154, inplace=True)` (same for `pharma`). Then you create x and y columns by doing `appart['x'] = appart.geometry.x` and `appart['y'] = appart.geometry.y` (same for `pharma`). Then you can use the ballTree as described in my answer, the returned distance will be in meters.

Comment: @ArnaudH don't hesitate to tell if you prefer that i expand my explanation in my answer instead than in comments !

Comment: It's perfect in comment but as you want :)

I just change the metrics to the balltree :
`tree = BallTree(pharma[['lat_r', 'lng_r']].values, leaf_size=2, metric='haversine')`

And i convert my degrees into radians with :
`appart['latitude_r']=pd.DataFrame(np.deg2rad(appart['latitude'].values))
appart['longitude_r']=pd.DataFrame(np.deg2rad(appart['longitude'].values))
pharma['lat_r']=pd.DataFrame(np.deg2rad(pharma['lat'].values))
pharma['lng_r']=pd.DataFrame(np.deg2rad(pharma['lng'].values))
`

It's still not good but it's a little problem which will be solve in few time i think :)

Comment: Oh they are a limitation of characters in comment, and it's true that i don't understant what is a coordinate system, if you have some documentation about this and why it will solve my problem i'am open ;)

Comment: Great, i forgot about the 'haversine' metric ! Note that the output will also be in radians in this case.

Comment: Regarding the question about "coordinate systems" maybe you can start with an introduction like this: http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc16/tech-workshops/tw_1746-46.pdf . Basically, the idea is to transform coordinates in latitude longitude (corresponding to the position on a global 3D spherical surface) to coordinates on a flat 2d surface. There is not "one way" to do this for the whole world without introducing deformations ; that's why local projections (such as [epsg:2154 for France](https://epsg.io/2154)) exists.