# Delete "almost duplicates" rows of string based on fuzzy matching with a lot of lines (>50 000)

Tags: python, duplicates, nearest-neighbor, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I have 50 000 words like :

- add
- to add
- chicken
- a chicken
- eat the chicken
- to eat
- ...

And i want to drop the line which have a high fuzzy similarity with other lines.

Then the output should be:

- add
- to eat
- chicken
- ...

I can't calculate every fuzzy match (50 000**2 match is to high), and i search a methode like the KD-Tree / Ball-Tree but working with string distance (Levenstein distance, fuzzy distance ...)

I prefer to use only python, but i'am open mind ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You need to specify more the method. Why keep  `chicken` vs `eat the chickens` for example? In overview, you can create a set of all words other than articles. Use that set as keys in a dict pointing to a list of phrases containing that word. Sort the lists on len. Keep the shortest.

Comment: **I allready specify, i said "drop the line which have a high fuzzy similarity"** But drop which one? Shortest? Longest? First or last? It is a decent question but you need to be more specific. Use a subset of actual data with actual results you want to see. The example is bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the module [thefuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz/tree/master).

```
from thefuzz import process

word_list = ['add', 'to add', 'chicken', 'eat the chicken', 'to eat']
deduped_word_list = process.dedupe(word_list, threshold=60)
print(deduped_word_list)
```

Output : `['to add', 'to eat', 'eat the chicken']`

By definition, they retain the longest string for a class of duplicates as they expect it to have maximal information. If you want the shortest string, you can refactor their code :)

Check [process.dedupe](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz/blob/83bea3d4a109a5d0c2e07334b504953cda4959c5/thefuzz/process.py#L405) to learn more!

Answer (score -1):

After personnal search on other topic, i didn't find fast solution using simple python librairie

But i get the two ideas to solv my problem :
1.to vectorize each "string", by example :
"a chicken" -> (0,0,0,0,...1,0,...1,0,0)
And use a KD-Tree/Ball-Tree with sklearn (see my topic to implement it: [Find nearest point in other dataframe (WITH A LOT OF DATA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893719/find-nearest-point-in-other-dataframe-with-a-lot-of-data/58942469#58942469))

2.Stem every strings and apply a .drop_duplicates with pandas ;)